# Windows 10 XAMPP Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I have some projects running with XAMPP on my computer and its running on Windows 10. I have been using XAMPP for the past 3 to 4 months with no problem at all, but yesterday suddenly after a windows update, it won't open the Apache server saying :

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

I have not been able to find a solution and i tryed many things I could find online, so please if anyone could help me?

EDIT**
I have rebooted my PC a couple of times since this happend and nothing changed! However i forgot to say while posting that the MySQL server is running like it used to! Apache server don't however.

EDIT 2**
I tried many things, such as uninstalling XAMPP and installing it back again, running Apache directly from CMD to check any errors (none were displayed), changed port configurations for Apache even tho port 80 seems to be listening and I also tried installing other XAMPP-like programs (such as MAMP, WAMP) but nothing really came out and no XAMPP-like programs worked! Does anyone have any suggestions?
Also, weird thing, XAMPP runs perfectly on my second PC (Windows 7), like it used to, but I want it in this PC, since here I do my development (The other is old and slow).
Also, now XAMPP seems not to throw the "red-line errors" in it's console, it is just saying:

```
[Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...
```

And it does not seems to change.
THIS ONLY HAPPENS WHEN I RUN AS ADMIN XAMPP!

Comment: Did you reboot your PC?  If XAMPP failed to restart after the first reboot, did you try rebooting again?  How exactly do you start XAMPP: manually, or does it auto-start?  What is the exact error after your latest restart?  Please edit your post and add this information.  ALSO: look [here](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/05/fixing-a-blocked-port-in-xampp/)

Comment: Could be many things which lead to this, check log and post it here, we need more info.

Comment: I reboted my PC a couple of times, but nothing changes, all i keep getting is this error i posted on the main post. I start XAMPP manualy, not with the auto-start. I checked the video too and the article but did't solve my problem, i keep getting these same lines evry time i press start on Apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after diging to my log/error files and this is what is was displayed;

```
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
 www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

PHP Warning:  'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.28 in Unknown on line 0

So i found a solution from anoher article at SO which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260070/xampp-apache-server-wont-start-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)